# Are there specific edit guidelines for this SE?

Tags: discussion, editing

Have just found this SE and was reading through alot of the questions. I started editing a few questions to make for easier reading, as some of them are just a wall of text. I do have some experience of editing questions on other SE.

I noticed the one question I was editing, had been edited before. To fix a single typo. It was from a user with a fairly substantial rep, so they must know what is acceptable for this site. So it made me stop and wonder if I was going overboard and what this particular SE sites guidelines may be. Aside from the standard guidelines found in the [editing] page. I don't want to accidently rock the boat.

**Are there any Sustainable Living SE specific editing guidelines?** Any 'unspoken' guidelines that you may only find out through site experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no specific edit guidelines for this site. I think we have about a handful of people who occasionally edit other people's posts, mostly to improve the meaning of a question. It's rare to see edits just to improve typos. Generally speaking, walls of text are improved if it's a question, but if it's an answer people often don't bother.

I'm not sure why this is. I guess there aren't many people around who like to spend time on this.

BTW I approved both your edits. Thank you for improving this site.

Comment: Why edit questions but not answers? Because we have to share questions, but not answers. If I see a question with problems, I'm not going to create a duplicate question just to fix some formatting or typos. But if I see a bad answer, I'll definitely write my own answer and hope it rises to the top.